# The custom handy mean function doesn't work correctly

Tags: r

The function I defined returns a different result than the R function.

```
n <- 100
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
x <- rnorm(n)

mean(x > 0)
# [1] 0.54


aver <- function(x, n) {
  h <- 0
  j <- 0
  for (i in x) {
    if (i > 0) {
      h <- h + i
      j <- j + 1
    }
  }
  return(h/j)
}

aver(x, 0)
# [1] 0.7949533
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `mean(x[x > 0])` to subset x and then you will get the same answer. `x > 0` on the other hand gives a boolean vector, i.e. you attempted to calculate the mean of this boolean (which is a value between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 1):

```
aver <- function(x, n) {
  h <- 0
  j <- length(x)
  for (i in x) {
    if (i > n) h <- h + 1 # We add 1 to h. h contains the number of x > n
  }
  return(h/j)
}

aver(x, 0)
#> 0.54
```